# Is there a possibility to select text by mouse double click and drag the selectet text by mouse to another webElement in Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a possibility to select text by mouse double click and drag the selectet text by mouse to another webElement in Selenium Webdriver Python[image: sele]

Comment: Why do you want to _DragnDrop_ instead of `send_keys()`?

Comment: because am working on automating a webform filler, and the first field can not be copied and the second one must be filled with the data of the first one (it's a captcha)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your site")

source = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your element to drag')
destination = driver.find_element_by_xpath('element to drag to')

ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source= source, target= destination).perform()
```

Comment: Thanx Manish, But I want to move the real mouse, so I used "MousePos" to locate the cordinates of the cursor, and I used "pyautogui" to do the work, and It Worked

Comment: `pyautogui.moveTo(242, 640)

        pyautogui.drag(70, 0, duration=0.35)  # move right
        
        pyautogui.drag(0, 82, duration=0.45)  # move down`